# Changing CSS styles with PHP and jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm executing a PHP if/else statement.

However, I want the code to do something like this :

```
<?php 

    if ($condition == true){ 
       echo 'ITS TRUE!'; 
    }else { 
       #id-element.css('display':'none'); 
    } 

?>
```

**Note that the ELSE statement executes a jQuery line that changes the css style of the element involved.**

How do i go about doing this?

Anyone have any suggestions / examples of how I could implement a PHP if/else and change css styles with jQuery inside the PHP if/else statement?

Comment: You could just output the CSS in the page head, inside a `<style>` tag - no need for jQuery then

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can echo the HTML for a style element and throw the CSS inside that.

```
else {
    echo '<style type="text/css">
        #id-element {
            display: none;
        }
        </style>';
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Reckon you could do something like this:

```
<?php
    if ($condition == true): 
         echo 'ITS TRUE!'; 
    else: 
?> 
    //put whatever html/style/script you want here, for example
    <script>
        $( '#id-element' ).css('display', 'none');
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```